# Управление множеством одинаковых сайтов

Tags: cms

Требуется какое-то решение для управления множеством одинаковых сайтов (аренда жилья, кемпингов). То есть это не каталог на одном сайте, а именно разные сайты.

Функционал простой - главная страница, страница контактов, форма обратной связи (отправка содержимого формы на email).

Структура сайтов всегда одинаковая. Разница в изображениях, заголовке страницы и контактных данных и паре блоков текста с описанием.

Есть ли какое-то готовое решение для управления множеством таких сайтов?

Comment: А что вы понимаете под управлением?

Comment: Если бы это был WordPress, можно было бы использовать один сайт с плагином Multiple Domains. Отличающиеся блоки выводить через шорткоды в зависимости от текущего домена

Comment: Под управлением я понимаю - изменение содержимого некоторых блоков (замена текста, изображения, контактов), назначение доменного имени, и собственно чтобы это все стало онлайн